# background on emulator being stretched

Tags: java, android

I have a background on my android app with is a png image.  It is 800 x 480 px in size.
It is being stretched width wise and hence does not look as I intend it to.  As the image is actually the background of the app and not just an imageView I was unable to use the android:scaleType="centerCrop" to get the image to scale equally.

I need the image to fill the background equally.

I have also tried using NinePatch drawable but the results were not good at all on this - The image became blurred or was OK when being stretched vertically but not width wise.

[image: before image]
[image: after image as seen on emulator]

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/menu"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Is there any other command I can use to get the background to display correctly?

Comment: fill your background with black and put only your logo in center as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to resolve this use draw9patch

android-sdk/tools/draw9patch

https://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: I have used this, but did not get correct results.  I tried the following using this tool:
1. drawing a line all the way around the image - this made no difference at all
2. drawin a line at the top and the left hand side of teh image - this fixed the stretch when it was stretching verticall but not horizontally.

Comment: I worked on the draw 9 patch tool a little longer and got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

use imageview

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/your_image"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
/>
```

check this also [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

```
ImageView.ScaleType     CENTER_CROP

Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).
```

Comment: Hi, I used the above code but the image is still being stretched I also tried the different scale types in the link you provided (thanks for this by the way).  I noted that if the image view is android:src, instead of android:background then the image is not stretched but just too big for the screen.